# Why doesn't ivyde see one of my dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, ivy, ivyde

I have an Eclipse build, using ivyde, that doesn't see one of my dependencies.

The build works fine in normal ant from the commandline.

The particular missing dependency is one of our own (not an Apache or more standard dependency). But again, it works from commandline ant builds just fine.

Maybe Eclipse uses some special defaults that don't exist in the command line version of pure ant ivy builds?

Comment: How do you resolve this dependency in ant? How did you configure ivyde? Did you configure ivyde to use your ivysettings.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure, that Eclipse/IvyDE-Plugin has the same settings as ant.

If you have a custom `ivysettings.xml`, make it known to eclipse. IvyDE will use it to resolve the dependencies. If it is not set `maven repo` is used as a standard.

You can **configure** the IvyDE settings like:

[image: IvySettings]

**For debugging** / errors you can open the ivy console and set its loglevel to debug.

[image: ivydebug]

Comment: This is an AMAZING answer :) You just saved my life.  I guess Ivy is basically like maven - the settings have to be configured correctly for the dependencies to be resolved, and if the settings file which sometimes gets is missing, because your not paying attention , your screwed.  IS THERE A WAY TO HAVE IVY FAIL IN ABSENCE OF a compatible SETTINGS FILE ?  this would be a really useful safety measure, to force people to properly run the ivy build, or not run it at all .

Comment: @jayunit100 ivyde will always fall back to the default, in ant you have the ivysettings task, which you can give an ivysettings. this will fail if the file cannot be found.